# Count numbers generated in MsgBox VBA

Tags: vba, msgbox

I would like to play with random numbers generated in MsgBox.
I have a functional loop and I would like to find out 2 things:

1st The program generates 30 random integers (eg from 10 to 50). Find out how many of them are within a certain interval (e.g., from 25 to 35)

2nd Find out the final sum of generated numbers in MsgBox

```
Dim b As Byte
Dim f As Single
Dim ret As String
ret = ""

For b = 1 To 30
    f = Round(Rnd() * 40) + 10
    ret = ret + Chr(10) + Str(f)

    Next b
        MsgBox ret
```

Comment: Sounds great. What's the question/problem exactly? Note that a newline on Windows is Chr(10)+Chr(13), i.e. `vbCrLf`, or even better, `vbNewLine`. Lastly you might want to make it a habit to use the `&` string concatenation operator to avoid surprises.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a condition for your `ret` total. e.g. `If f >= 25 And f <= 35 Then ret = ret & vbNewLine & CStr(f)` - note the conversion function `CStr` was probably what you intended to use here.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu! I will start using "vbNewLine" and &" from now on.

Following your advice I have adjusted the code and my 1st task is almost finished.
What I would like to add is a code which will give me a SUM and COUNT of random generated numbers from the MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

Following your advice I had created this.
Code is generating MsgBox with 2 columns - all random numbers and final sum.

```
Sub C5b()

    Dim b As Byte
    Dim f As Single
    Dim ret As String
    Dim f1 As Single
    ret = ""
    f1 = 0

    For b = 1 To 20
        f = Round(Rnd() * 40) + 10
        f1 = f + f1
        ret = ret & vbNewLine & Str(f)

        Next b
            MsgBox ret + Str(f1)

End Sub
```

Over all it's doing exactly what I needed and it helped me to move forward in my training - Thanks!